# How to log which policy and claim were checked

Tags: authentication, logging, .net-core

(this is my first question, many thanks for your help getting this question right and matching guidelines)

I'm building a small web application based on dotnet core (3.1). To control access to my controllers, I use this kind of decorator:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Stuff>> GetStuff(){
...
```

I have a custom `AuthenticationHandler` that extracts my role and injects it in claims.

The whole system works as intended. For instance, if I make a call to this route (as an admin), I can see this in the log:

```
[12:46:59 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5002/api/getstuff/  
[12:46:59 INF] Authorization was successful.
```

If I make the same request without admin role, I get this:

```
[12:46:59 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5002/api/getstuff/  
[12:56:36 INF] Authorization failed.
```

Now, for the purpose of my problem, let's add another decorator:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
[Authorize(Policy = "CustomAccessPolicy")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Stuff>> GetStuff(){
...
```

**Question**

Here is my problem: if the user does not match `CustomAccessPolicy` OR if he/she is not an Administrator, I'll get the **same** log, which is a problem for me.

What can I do to get a more accurate log, such as:

```
[12:46:59 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5002/api/getstuff/  
[12:56:36 INF] Checked Role: Administrator. Success.
[12:56:36 WRN] Check Policy CustomAccessPolicy: Failed!
[12:56:36 WRN] Authorization failed.
```

How can I get this accurate log of policy/claims/authorization checks?

I believe it can be a matter of configuration (log level on some component?), or maybe I need to reimplement some method/bind to some events?

Many thanks!